# AdNetworkSupport Adaptor - AdColony 3 Support

Tags: ios, swift, ads, mopub, adcolony

Just tried to integrate AdColony with Mopub and ran into a bunch of errors. Seems that with the latest 3.x.x version, AdColony has made some significant changes.

Anyone have an updated adaptor?

I opened an issue [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/adnetworksupport-adaptor-adcolony-3/76364)

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, AdColony has changed their SDK's API at 3.X and is not backward compatible with any AdColony 2.X.
They don't have any `Protocol` no more. This is the latest API document:
https://adcolony-www-common.s3.amazonaws.com/Appledoc/3.1.0/index.html

It seems that Mopub has supported AdColony 3.X since 4.12.0:
https://github.com/mopub/mopub-ios-sdk/compare/4.12.0...master